# Visual C++ Thread?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, c++-cli

I have a Visual C++ forms application for Windows, using Visual Studio 2010. I want to fire off a thread under this event:

```
private: System::Void Form1_Shown(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

}
```

How can I do this? I have been searching for hours and it doesn't seem to work for me :( can someone show me how I need to set up a thread that runs another method, and how to set up that method, and everything else (declarations, namespaces you use, etc)?

Comment: Use backGroundWorker1->RunWorkerAsync().  Lots of help in the MSDN library.

Comment: This is C++/CLI, any particular reason for not using C# if you need to use managed code?

Comment: You searched for hours and didn't come across the [Thread class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.aspx)..?

Comment: No, I came across it. I could not get it working, I need a real example of how it is to be set up in a simple application, like a demonstration. Also, I want to explore Visual C++, which is why I do not want to use C#. Could you give the simplest case of backGroundWorker?

Comment: @Ovidius : The documentation I linked to _does have_ a working C++/CLI example. Make sure your language filter has C++ checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to explore Visual C++, you will probably be better off working with unmanaged C++, and creating your application using the Win32 API and MFC for the GUI. C++/CLI is a very powerful language, but it basically requires you to know both C++ and C# before you even get started.

That said, here's how you do it:

```
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Threading;

static void MyThreadFunc()
{
   // Insert code to be run on the other thread here.
}

void Form1_Shown(Object^ sender, EventArgs^ e)
{
    Thread^ thread = gcnew Thread(gcnew ThreadStart(&ClassName::MyThreadFunc));
    // If MyThreadFunc is an instance method, use "gcnew ThreadStart(this, &ClassName::MyThreadFunc)" to get the delegate.
    thread->Start();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked well, and it helps me learn. Now a quick question, how can I pass this->progressBar to MyThreadFunc()? What is the syntax for declaring the MyThreadFunc() with a progressBar object type?

Comment: There is a way to pass the progress bar to the thread method (Look at the Thread constructor that takes a `ParameterizedThreadStart`, rather than a `ThreadStart`), but that's not how I'd do it. Instead, I'd make the thread method an instance method, rather than a static method. That way, you can access all the fields & properties of `this`, and access the ProgressBar that way. Be careful though, it's generally a bad idea to access a UI control from your own thread, accessing it from anything other than the UI thread will almost certainly cause a deadlock.